In which case do the center of buoyancy center of gravity coincide for a body with uniform density. Would it be completely submerged or just immersed
I read other as well in this topic but they dont exactly explain about the body being partially immersed or completely submerged. I mean does the coincidence of centre of buoyancy and centre of gravity only occur when body is completely submerged or is it that the body need not be so. If it also occurs when it is partially immersed how would it be possible?

Think about a log that has been in the water for a long time and soaked up a large amount of water.  That log might be still floating, but just below the surface.

So it must be underwater for coincidence, right?

I'm not sure how you are defining "coincide", but the following applies to the relative locations of the center of gravity (CG) and center of buoyancy (CB).
For a body and liquid of uniform density the CG of the body and the CB will be at the same location when the body is completely submerged (floating completely submerged or sinking). That's because the CB, which is the center of the volume of liquid displaced by the body and the CG, which is the center of the volume of the body, are one and the same when the body is completely submerged. See FIG A for a sphere. To be completely submerged the density of the body must be equal to or greater than the density of the liquid.
For a body that floats partially submerged (because its density is less than the liquid), the CG and CB will not be at the same location. But they will be vertically aligned for rotational equilibrium with the CG above the CB. See FIGs B and C for a half submerged sphere (density half that of the liquid). That's because the location of the CG of the body doesn't change but the location of the CB depends on the volume of fluid displaced. .
Hope this helps.


What do you mean by floating completely submerged is it like wood floating just below surface level?

@AnishShrestha it means none of the body is above the liquid level. If the density of the body exactly equals the density of the liquid you can carefully release the sphere in FIG A anywhere under the liquid line but near the surface and it will stay there. It the density of the sphere in FIG  A is greater than the liquid, it will sink. In either case the body is completely submerged. In one case it remain stationary. In the other it sinks.
